# Ionic: Impelement Diagnostic Plugin (no ngCordova Plugin)

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to implement a common cordova Plugin (which is not available through ngCordova right now) into my Ionic project.

I've installed the plugin via CLI

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

After that I injected it into my module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards', 'Diagnostic'])
```

And then I created a Factory:

```
.factory('LocationSettings', ['$q', 'Diagnostic', function($q, Diagnostic) {
  return {
    getLocationSettings: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      Diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(result) {
        console.log("Location is " + (result ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+err);
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

After that I want to redirect the user to the location settings if he disabled GPS permission for the app.

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $state, LocationSettings) {
    LocationSettings.getLocationSettings().then(function(result) {
      alert(result);
    }, function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });
}
```

I tested it on my real device (iPhone) but it doesn't work. Actually it doesn't throw an error, I just get a blank white screen.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the [GitHub README](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), there is no Angular module available to be injected.

You need to install the plugin (you did) and then directly use it in a "pure javascript way" (no Angular way).

It's located in the namespace `cordova.plugins.diagnostic`.